# how can i get the last messages of a user with all other users in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

[image]

```
$options = array('order' => array('MemberMessage.send_date_time' => 'desc'),
  'fields' => array('MemberMessage.id','MemberMessage.message'),
  'group' => 'MemberMessage.message_reciever_id');

 $this->MemberMessage->recursive = 0;
 $MemberMessages = $this->MemberMessage->find('all',$options);
```

Comment: Do you want to only last user message?

Comment: please try to better explain your needs

Comment: i need only last user message. like if user A message user B at time 10:0:0 and 7:0:0 , and send message to user C at time 11:0:0 ,11:10:0 then result will be the messages of user A with B at time 10:0:0 and with user C at time 11:10:0

Comment: Can you give sample data return by above query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve this by using this query:

$MemberMessages =  $this->MemberMessage->query("SELECT *
                                                        FROM (

```
                                                    SELECT conversation_user_id,message, send_date_time
                                                    FROM (

                                                    SELECT DISTINCT message_reciever_id AS conversation_user_id, id, message, send_date_time
                                                    FROM (

                                                    SELECT *
                                                    FROM member_messages
                                                    WHERE message_sender_id =".$this->request->data['MemberMessage']['user_id'].
                                                    " ORDER BY send_date_time DESC
                                                    ) AS t
                                                    GROUP BY message_reciever_id
                                                    UNION
                                                    SELECT DISTINCT message_sender_id AS conversation_user_id, id, message, send_date_time
                                                    FROM (

                                                    SELECT *
                                                    FROM member_messages
                                                    WHERE message_reciever_id =".$this->request->data['MemberMessage']['user_id'].
                                                    " ORDER BY send_date_time DESC
                                                    ) AS u
                                                    GROUP BY message_sender_id
                                                    ) AS CONVERSATION
                                                    ORDER BY send_date_time DESC
                                                    ) AS conversation
                                                    GROUP BY conversation_user_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be enough?

```
$lastMessage = $this->Message->find('first', array(
    'order' => array('Message.created' => 'desc')
));
```

Good luck!

Comment: i need all last messages of user's with other users

Comment: As Bob suggest it returns only last single message